# deliver_sm request with unicode charecter

Tags: java, sms, unicode-string, smpp

I am trying to develop a smsc simulator which will send deliver_sm to gateway. Now i am able to send deliver_sm request to gateway successfully.But this time i need to send Unicode character as a massage body.When ever i am trying to send unicode characters the gateway is not recognizing it .It is showing as invalid keyword as massage. Now i guess my 16-bit encoding of the massage is not correct.Here is my code.Please give me corrected code if possible.

```
try {

    ByteBuffer ed = new ByteBuffer();
    DeliverSM request = new DeliverSM();

    private String message="text";
    private SimulatorPDUProcessor proc;

    request.setEsmClass((byte)Data.SM_UDH_GSM); //Set UDHI Flag Data.SM_UDH_GSM=0×40
    request.setDataCoding((byte) ((byte) 0*04));

    ed.appendByte((byte) 6); // UDH Length
    ed.appendByte((byte) ((byte) 0*04)); // IE Identifier
    ed.appendByte((byte) 4); // IE Data Length
    ed.appendByte((byte) 00) ; //Reference Number 1st Octet
    ed.appendByte((byte) 00) ; //Reference Number 2nd Octet

    try {
        ed.appendString(message, Data.ENC_UTF16_BE);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    request.setShortMessage(message,Data.ENC_UTF16);

    request.setSourceAddr("sourceAdd");
    request.setDestAddr("919865851257");
    proc.serverRequest(request);

    System.out.println("Message sent.");
    try {
        generateResult(sourceAdd,"sent");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (WrongLengthOfStringException e) {
    System.out.println("Message sending failed ");
    event.write(e, "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need set

```
submitSM.setDataCoding((byte)(0x08)); // UCS-2
submitSM.setShortMessage( MessageStr, "UTF-16" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UTF-8 encoding instead. Possibly you will need to actually encode your data first.

Disclaimer: I have no idea of the `deliver_sm` API, *but SMS does use UTF-8*. <- I stand corrected, [USC-16 is used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service#Message_size) for messages that don't fit 7-bit and 8-bit encodings.

Comment: I tried it.I tried to convert hindi text in this mannar also::try {
      
      String string = "हिंदि भाषा ";
      byte[] utf8 = string.getBytes("UTF-8");

      
      string = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
      System.out.println(string);
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
  }         but when ever i tried to compile this code it is showing like this:: Some character can,t be mapped using cp1252 character encoding....

Comment: Nope, SMS uses UTF-16 (with datacoding=8)